# how to link external libraries and external include directory in configure.ac and makefile.am

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

if I want to create configure.ac and makefile.am from scratch to build my project, the project contains project__include directory, project__lib directory and src directory inside it there are some .c files and .h header files
all what I need is to link the src directory to the project__include and project__lib directory, and link the src with pthread library. 
can any one help me?
also, is AC_CHECK_HEADER is used to include header file into the project? or just for checking if it is included already in the project.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want or what isn't working? The autotools have a very steep [learning curve](https://autotools.io/index.html). It is intended to make life easy for the user - not so much for the developer.